# mysql row number with where clause issue

Tags: mysql

I have following query where I calculate row number :

```
 SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rnkk, tdate, billno, party_name, net_total, pid FROM purchase_bill_wise  , (SELECT @rank := 0) rnk;
```

which returns the row number perfectly. Issue occurs when I put a where clause in the query like below :

```
SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rnkk, tdate, billno, party_name, net_total, pid FROM purchase_bill_wise WHERE tdate = '2013-09-18' ,  (SELECT @rank := 0) rnk;
```

I am getting Error Code: 1064

Comment: You probably want an `order by`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross join should be after the `select ... from table_name`

```
SELECT 
 @rank := @rank + 1 AS rnkk, 
 tdate, 
 billno, 
 party_name, 
 net_total, 
 pid 
 FROM purchase_bill_wise,(SELECT @rank := 0) rnk
 WHERE tdate = '2013-09-18'
 ;
```